# Ardunio, decoding a string at postion N

Tags: string, serial-port, arduino

I'm having this little problem with some easy code, basically what I'm doing is sending information via the serial port via a program I wrote in Java. The information is getting their for basic statements (IE, can turn on lights and stuff) but I'm having errors getting it to decode strings with number values send to it.

So for example, I'm sending strings that look like this

```
BS//:+000/+000/+000
```

and the decoding method I'm using looks like this.

After adding the string via this:

```
 if (inputString.startsWith("BS//:")) //**fixed
    {
      inputInfoToBaseStepper(inputString);
      baseStepperRunAction(baseStepperRotCount, baseStepperRotStepSize, baseStepperTime);
    }
```

Sends it too...

```
void inputInfoToBaseStepper(String baseStepper) 
{
  baseStepperRotCount = baseStepper.substring(6,9).toInt(); 
  baseStepperRotStepSize = baseStepper.substring(10,13).toInt();
  baseStepperTime = baseStepper.substring(15,18).toInt();
}
```

Which should decode and run

```
void baseStepperRunAction (int rotations, int StepSize, int delayTime)
{
  for (int rotations; rotations >=0; rotations--)
  {
    baseStepper.step(StepSize);
    delay(delayTime);
  }
}
```

Problem seems to be that it doesn't decode... ideas I'm sort of lost at this stage. :/

(total past of the code, I know the information is getting there, just not compiling like it should.)

```
#include <Stepper.h>
//#include <HardwareSerial.h>

// int intensity = 0;               // led intensity this is needed just as example for this sketch
String inputString = "";         // a string to hold incoming data (this is general code you can reuse)
boolean stringComplete = false;  // whether the string is complete (this is general code you can reuse)

int stepsPerRevolution = 64;  //at 5.625 degrees a step

// initialize the stepper library on pins 8 through 11:
Stepper baseStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 2,3,4,5); // protocols start with //BS:
Stepper shoulderStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 6,7,8,9); // protocols start with //SS:
Stepper armStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 10,11,12,13); // protocols start with //AS:

//--------baseStepper--------//
int baseStepperRotCount = 0; //how many rotations in the for loop is needed
int baseStepperRotStepSize = 0; // how large should the steps be...
int baseStepperTime = 0; //delay time needed between each step (delay); so the stepper can do it's work.
//--------shoulderStepper--------//
int shoulderStepperRotCount =0;



void setup() {
  // initialize serial: (this is general code you can reuse)
  Serial.begin(115200);

}

void loop() {
  // when a newline arrives:
  if (stringComplete) {

    //these are test if statements, they serve no purpose after the intial boot, but must be included to test the connectivity;
      if (inputString.startsWith("alpha"))
      {
        boolean msgRecognized = true;
        pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        inputString = "";
        stringComplete = false;
      } 
      else if (inputString.startsWith("beta"))
      {
        boolean msgRecognized = true;
        pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);
        inputString = "";
        stringComplete = false;
      } 
      //---------------------///


     //these statements set the engines and prepare for running of the program.
     if (inputString.startsWith("//BS:")) //   "BS//:+000/+000/+000"
    {
      inputInfoToBaseStepper(inputString);
      baseStepperRunAction(baseStepperRotCount, baseStepperRotStepSize, baseStepperTime);
    }
    else if (inputString.startsWith("//SS:"))
    {
      //inputInfoToShoulderStepper();
      //outputConfirmed();
    }
    else if (inputString.startsWith("//AS:"))
    {
      //inputInfoToArmStepper();
     // outputConfirmed();
    }





    if(inputString.startsWith("alp://")) { // OK is a message I know (this is general code you can reuse)


      boolean msgRecognized = true;

      if(inputString.substring(6,10) == "kprs") { // KeyPressed }

        msgRecognized = false; // this sketch doesn't know other messages in this case command is ko (not ok)


      // Prepare reply message if caller supply a message id (this is general code you can reuse)
      int idPosition = inputString.indexOf("?id=");
      if(idPosition != -1) {
        String id = inputString.substring(idPosition + 4);
        // print the reply
        Serial.print("alp://rply/");
        if(msgRecognized) { // this sketch doesn't know other messages in this case command is ko (not ok)
          Serial.print("ok?id=");
        } else {
          Serial.print("ko?id=");
        }
        Serial.print(id);
        Serial.write(255); // End of Message
        Serial.flush();
      }
    }
        // clear the string:
    inputString = "";
    stringComplete = false;
  }
}
}
/*
   Send listen messages
  int index = 0;
  for (index = 0; index < digitalPinListeningNum; index++) {
    if(digitalPinListening[index] == true) {
      int value = digitalRead(index);
      if(value != digitalPinListenedValue[index]) {
        digitalPinListenedValue[index] = value;
        Serial.print("alp://dred/");
        Serial.print(index);
        Serial.print("/");
        Serial.print(value);
        Serial.write(255); 
        Serial.flush();
      }
    }
  }

  for (index = 0; index < analogPinListeningNum; index++) {
    if(analogPinListening[index] == true) {
      int value = analogRead(index);
      if(value != analogPinListenedValue[index]) {
        analogPinListenedValue[index] = value;
        Serial.print("alp://ared/");
        Serial.print(index);
        Serial.print("/");
        Serial.print(value);
        Serial.write(255); // End of Message
        Serial.flush();
      }
    }
  }
} */

//this method decodes and stores inputs
void inputInfoToBaseStepper(String baseStepper) 
{
  baseStepperRotCount = baseStepper.substring(6,9).toInt(); //       B S / / : + 0 0 0 / + 0 0 0 / + 0 0 0
  baseStepperRotStepSize = baseStepper.substring(10,13).toInt();//   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
  baseStepperTime = baseStepper.substring(15,18).toInt();
}



//this method runs the base stepper off the decoded actions.
void baseStepperRunAction (int rotations, int StepSize, int delayTime)
{
  for (int rotations; rotations >=0; rotations--)
  {
    baseStepper.step(StepSize);
    delay(delayTime);
  }
}





/*
  SerialEvent occurs whenever a new data comes in the
 hardware serial RX.  This routine is run between each
 time loop() runs, so using delay inside loop can delay
 response.  Multiple bytes of data may be available.
 This is general code you can reuse.
 */



void serialEvent() {

  while (Serial.available() && !stringComplete) {
    // get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    // add it to the inputString:
    inputString += inChar;
    // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
    // so the main loop can do something about it:
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You say the string starts with BS//: but the code says //BS: ??

Comment: O.O Oh my lord... could that be it, I might of just done a mistake on sending it. Let me check quick.

Comment: Fixed an obvious problem, but it still isn't decoding that string the way I need it too unfortunately.

Comment: Have you considered using Processing? It's based on Java (and you can use native Java as well) and it plays very well with Arduino.
Anyway: if the values you are sending are in the byte range you should try sending bytes instead of strings to save yourself all those substrings. Look at this code (using processing): https://processing.org/discourse/beta/num_1263838688.html

Comment: subString() index starts at 0, not 1. All your calls are off by 1.

Comment: UncleO: I checked the code. I did include that for reference, the string is assembled via 0 at B... unless arduino starts with a null character that I was unaware of? Thus making B positions 1 instead of 0... That would literally make me melt down at this point XD.

@elpoto, I found out yesterday, to table flipping rage that half the problem with this thus far is the arduino can't handle it's strings well. 8-bit processor does not play well with multiple comparisons. Switched it over to a character array, now it seems to be working better internally, but now can't get the information to it.